# Graph API for Outlook message restore

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I had taken backup of my mail box using below rest API
 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages 
But from My side this email msg deleted and i want to restore it again . 
How i can do it using Rest API. 
I tried with
 POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages 
and body with message. 
but the message added as a draft not actual message.
 Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, when you create an email it will always save as draft unless it has been sent.

Try find the returned message id from the message creation POST, then issue a secondary POST to send it:

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/send

Ref: [message: send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)